# Struct vs Class using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, class, struct

I was working on some code when I discovered something I don't fully understand so I created the following test code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string myKey = "bla";
        var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        var list2 = new List<Test>();


        var bla1 = (from a in list where a.Key == myKey select a.Value).FirstOrDefault();
        var bla2 = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == myKey).Value;

        var bla3 = (from a in list2 where a.Key == myKey select a.Value).FirstOrDefault();
        var bla4 = list2.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == myKey).Value;

    }

    struct Test
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public Test(string key, string value)
        {
            Key = key;
            Value = value;
        }
    }
```

Now as long as Test is a struct all of the 4 bla-lines work fine. But as soon as I change `Test` to be a `class` instead of a `struct` bla4 fails. How can this be? Isn't bla4 just another (lambda) way of doing bla3 and therefore should behave the same? Why does it make a difference whether the list contains a `struct's` or `classes`? And is there a way to have a lambda version of bla4 that doesn't throw an exception and instead returns null like the others?

Comment: Can you do `?.Value` instead of `.Value` ?

Comment: The default of a class type is null. The default of a struct is an empty struct. That's why `FirstOrDefault(..).Value` will fail with a NullReferenceException

Comment: Unfortunately no as this context doesn't yet allow C#6 code..

Comment: @MemphiZ ah too bad..

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Please consider converting your comment into an answer.

Comment: @Codor that's not enough to be an answer yet

Comment: "Isn't bla4 just another way of doing bla3 and therefore should behave the same?" No, they are not the same.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Shouldn't bla3 fail as well then?

Comment: @MemphiZ why? A query doesn't run until you try to access the results, eg with `FirstOrDefault()`. The query doesn't return anything, so `FirstOrDefault()` returns a default value. In `bla3` you don't try to access that default. In `bla4` you try to read the `.Value` property of the default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default of a class type is null. The default of a struct is an empty struct. That's why `FirstOrDefault(..).Value` will fail with a NullReferenceException.

You should check that `FirstOrDefault()` did return something before trying to access the result.

```
var item = list2.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == myKey);
var bla4 = (item == null)?null:item.Value;
```

In C# 6 and later you can use the `?.` operator, to perform the same check:

```
var item = list2.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == myKey)?.Value;
```

Another option is to use `??` to replace null with a default value.

```
var item = list2.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == myKey) ?? new Test();
var bla4 = item.Value;
```

It's common to create a special `Empty` object to use in such cases, eg:

```
class Test
{
    //...
    public static readonly Empty =new Test();
}

var item = list2.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == myKey) ?? Test.Empty;
var bla4 = item.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

A struct can never be `null`.

Therefore your call to `FirstOrDefault()` will actually cause a new struct to be constructed, because `default(struct)` is effectively `new(struct)`.

However if you change it to a class, then `default(class)` is `null`.

Thus the result of your call

```
list2.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == myKey)
```

will actually result in `null` being returned once it is a class. You should therefore recieve a **NullReferenceException** when trying to access `.Value`.

In layman terms what your bla3 acutally does is check if there is a matching item within the collection. If there is, it will select the property `Value` of that item, otherwise it will return the default of that property's type.

Your bla4 instead looks if it finds an item that matches the `Key` property. If it does, it selects the first of those items, if it does not, it creates a default of that item's type and returns that. You then try to acces that return value's `Value` property.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't bla4 just another (lambda) way of doing bla3 and therefore should behave the same?

No. `bla3` extracts some strings from the objects contained in a list. You then call `FirstOrDefault` on that set of strings and obtain a `null` value, because that set was empty.

`bla4` calls `FirstOrDefault` directly on the set of objects and you *then* obtain the string property `Value` from the defaulted object.

When the objects contained in your lists are structs, then the defaulted value will contain a `null` `Value` property. That's why they superficially seem similar. But be very clear - the order in which `Value` is being accessed and `FirstOrDefault` is being called is different, and `FirstOrDefault` is operating on different types of things.

Of course, exactly the same can be said for `bla2` vs `bla1`.